# Two phase mixing by virtue of high Reynolds number alone

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Consider a long horizontal tube into which I inject two immiscible fluids. Say, water and benzene. If one increases the pumping velocity i.e. flowrate / Reynolds number would one get intimate mixing of the two phases at some point?

[image]

If so, how high does one need to go in Re. The laminar to turbulent transition is well documented. But that transfer of momentum is substantially within the single phases, correct?

Normally, water and benzene are substantially imisscible and quick separating. i.e. If you stop stirring they quickly separate into distinct layers

Would at some point turbulence win over the phase separating effects of gravity?

The application is getting two phases to react together which needs intimate contact for extended time. I know that mechanical agitation & static mixers are conventionally used for this but am just wondering if a high enough Reynolds number can do the job too?

To elaborate, if one did an analog of the dye tracer experiment would a dye trail injected into one phase mix thoroughly across both? i.e. Given turbulence is there good mixing across the interface. Would the interface disappear at some point like it does when agitating a vessel with a impeller causing shear?

[image]

Comment: Yes, at some high enough Reynolds number an emulsion will form. See for e.g. Nadler & Mewes (1997) "Flow induced emulsification in the flow of two immiscible liquids in horizontal pipes",_International Journal of Multiphase Flow_,**23**, 55-68.

Comment: Hmm. This is actually a pretty interesting setup. I'm sure this effect is used somewhere in industry to make emulsions of some kind. I'm not knowledgeable enough to give an answer, but this might have some interesting applications. I'd probably search some of them if I was the one asking/trying to answer.